# How to color a specific line (condition is present) of a comment in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, colors, comments, line

Dear experts in Excel and VBA!
Could you tell me how you can color a certain line (condition - the presence of a certain word) in a Comments?
Comment consists of several lines, separated by Chr (10).
Example in picture1:
the comment has 4 lines, the second line contains the word "VBA", so this line should be highlighted in red.
The main problem is that the test word "VBA" can be in any line, there can be from 1 to 10+ lines.
I assumed that:

1. can move data from comment to cell
2. replace Chr (10) with some character, for example, "_"
3. distribute the text of the cell into columns through the "column distribution wizard"
4. search for the desired word "VBA" in the received cells
5. determine the cell number and understand that this is the number of the required line in the comment
6. based on the cell number, paint over the line number in the comment

Can you please tell me if my action logic is correct? Am I heading in the right direction?
If so, what is the correct way to carry out points 4-6?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E9xe.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

would this help?

"test" is the codename for the sheet I have set, change it according to your situation.

"i" will give you the line number, starting from 0. So in your example it would be 1.

**Edit**: Added `Exit For` in the if check.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_note()

    Dim strNote As String
    Dim arrNote As Variant
    Dim number_of_lines As Integer
    
    strNote = test.Range("A5").NoteText
    number_of_lines = Len(strNote) - Len(Replace(strNote, Chr(10), "")) + 1
    
    ReDim arrNote(1 To number_of_lines) As String
    
    arrNote = Split(strNote, Chr(10))
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = LBound(arrNote) To UBound(arrNote)
        
        If InStr(arrNote(i), "VBA") > 0 Then
            Debug.Print i, arrNote(i)
            Exit For 'If you are sure there won't be any other occurrence of VBA in there, why check the rest of the lines? Speeds code depending on circumstance.
        End If
        
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

**Edit 2**: Revised code to change the color of the comment line.

```
Sub test_note()

    Dim strNote As String
    Dim arrNote As Variant
    Dim number_of_lines As Integer
    
    strNote = test.Range("B5").NoteText
    number_of_lines = Len(strNote) - Len(Replace(strNote, Chr(10), "")) + 1
    
    ReDim arrNote(1 To number_of_lines) As String
    
    arrNote = Split(strNote, Chr(10))
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim startPos As Integer
    Dim number_of_chars As Integer
    
    startPos = 1
    
    ' Reset comment font color
    test.Range("B5").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = 0
    
    For i = LBound(arrNote) To UBound(arrNote)
        
        If InStr(arrNote(i), "VBA") > 0 Then
            number_of_chars = Len(arrNote(i))
            test.Range("B5").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(startPos, number_of_chars).Font.Color = vbRed
            Debug.Print i, arrNote(i), "startPos: " & startPos, "numChars: " & number_of_chars
        Else
            startPos = startPos + Len(arrNote(i)) + 1
        End If
        
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I looked at a few similar topics on the internet, but unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to use the line number to change the color to red. Could you clarify this?
I have found several options where they suggest using the InStr function to find the meaning of a symbol. But the meaning of the symbol and the line number are different things

Comment: Thank you! It's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Check this. Just running this VBA copies your comments to the cells
and highlights the lines containing "VBA", however, it does this for
all comments on all sheets

credit: https://martinbosanacvba.blogspot.com/2021/08/copying-comments-to-cells-and.html

```
Sub Demo()
    
    Dim tnahqb1 As Range
    Dim tnahqb2 As Range
    Dim tnahqb3 As Workbook
    Dim tnahqb4 As Worksheet
    Dim tnahqb5 As Variant
    Dim tnahqb6 As Integer
    Dim tnahqb7 As Integer
    Dim tnahqb8 As Integer
    Dim tnahqb9 As Integer
        
    For Each tnahqb10 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set tnahqb1 = tnahqb10.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)

        If tnahqb1 Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No comments in the sheet"
        Else
            For Each cell In tnahqb1
                cell.Value = cell.Comment.Text
                tnahqb5 = Split(cell.Comment.Text, Chr(10))
                tnahqb6 = UBound(tnahqb5) - LBound(tnahqb5) + 1

                For I = LBound(tnahqb5) To UBound(tnahqb5)
                    
                    If InStr(tnahqb5(I), "VBA") > 0 Then
                        tnahqb8 = Len(tnahqb5(I))
                        
                        With cell
                            tnahqb7 = InStr(cell.Comment.Text, tnahqb5(I))
                            tnahqb9 = tnahqb7 + tnahqb8
                            .Characters(tnahqb7, tnahqb8).Font.Color = vbRed
                        End With

                    End If

                Next I

            Next cell

        End If

    Next tnahqb10

End Sub
```

Comment: Ložančić Thanks for the information! A good link to a useful site.
Unfortunately, the macro does a slightly different function that I need.
I need to change the color of a row in a comments, not a cell. I could not change the code of your macro for myself.